# How to remove QScrollbar scroll buttons?

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qtwidgets

I want to style `QScrollBar` to look like this without the indicators in the end
[image]

I tried with the stylesheets:

```
QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical, QScrollBar::down-vertical  
{  
      border: none;  
      background: none;  
      color: none;  
}
```

But this hides the indicator arrow not the 2 buttons at the end
[image: This is what I have when I used the above style]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
QScrollBar:vertical {
background: #2f2f2f;
width: 15px;
margin: 0;
}

QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
background: #5b5b5b;
}

QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
height: 0px;
}

QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
height: 0px;
}

QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical {
height: 0px;
}
```

The classes you were looking for are **add-line**, **sub-line**, **add-page** and **sub-page**. Since they support the **box-model**, you can just set their height to 0 to make them disappear.

The code above was tested with Qt 5.9.